# Check whether a sprite on a specific region-AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I want to develop a game using Andengine and i am new to game developing field.

Here's the scenario for my simple Animal game

i have 3 regions a,b,c. a(domestic) and b(wild) are empty regions.c contains some pictures(sprites) of animals.when the game starts i want to move these animals to corresponding regions.the problem is how to check these animals moved to that particular region?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the regions Sprites and use

```
regionA.collidesWith(someAnimalSprite)
```

that returns true if the animal is on top of the given region.